# WCF RIA Service Has ServiceActivationException After App Pool Recycle With Unusual Error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I maintain a very large Silverlight application that makes heavy use of WCF RIA Services.

When a user is in the SL application, and the app pool running the RIA services is restarted for any reason, subsequent calls from the client all fail until the user closes the app, and comes in from the main entry point again.

The error in the logs does not correlate to the problem it describes.  These services work just fine if a user comes in "clean" essentially.

That said, there should be no reason for this, services do restart from time to time.

The error I get is below.  Does anyone have any ideas at what to look at?

```
[ServiceActivationException]: The service &#39;/ade/Services/DomainServices-Web-
 UserService.svc&#39; 
 cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  
 The exception message is: Entity &#39;DomainServices.Web.Role_Permission&#39; 
 has a property &#39;PermissionReference&#39; with an unsupported type
```

As stated above, this same call, 10 seconds before the restart, works swimmingly.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I cant answer your question but I can confirm that I get a very similar problem with our large Silverlight application that also makes heavy use of WCF RIA Services.  Every so often when the app pool recycles due it's scheduled recycle I see the following type of exceptions in the event log on the IIS server.

> WebHost failed to process a request.  Sender Information:
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/12036987 
>   Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service
>   '/Services/DomainServices-Web-ServiceLayer-ReportsDomainService.svc' cannot
>   be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception
>   message is: Invalid Include specification for member
>   'Activity.ActivitySourceType'. Non-projection includes can only be
>   specified on members with the AssociationAttribute applied.. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid Include specification for
>   member 'Activity.ActivitySourceType'. Non-projection includes can only
>   be specified on members with the AssociationAttribute applied.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.ValidateEntityTypes()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.Initialize()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.CreateDescription(Type
>   domainServiceType)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.GetDescription(Type
>   domainServiceType)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type
>   domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type
>   serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String
>   relativeVirtualPath)  Process Name: w3wp  Process ID: 15172

These exceptions are logged immediately after the application pool recycles and our users cannot use the application until I manually recycle the application pool again.

Have you made any progress on this?

Thanks
Kevin